# QListWidget.itemClicked doesn't work reliably with styled items

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QListWidget` containing one item, I want the item's texts to be partially bold, so I created a `QItemWidget` for it. I use a `QLabel` in it to display the partially bold texts, the code is as follows:

**ItemWidget.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QLayout, QLabel


class ItemWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ItemWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setLayout(self.__get_layout())

    def __get_layout(self) -> QHBoxLayout:
        label = QLabel("<b>bold</b> texts")
        widget_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        widget_layout.addWidget(label)
        widget_layout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetFixedSize)
        widget_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        return widget_layout
```

**Main.py**

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QListWidget, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QListWidgetItem

from ItemWidget import ItemWidget


class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        list_widget = QListWidget()
        list_widget.itemClicked.connect(self.on_item_clicked)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(list_widget)

        item_widget = ItemWidget()
        item = QListWidgetItem()
        list_widget.addItem(item)
        list_widget.setItemWidget(item, item_widget)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def on_item_clicked(self):
        print("Item clicked")


app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

This is the UI:

[image]

When I click on the item in the list, `Item clicked` should be printed to the output console. But the problem is, it only works if I don't click on the text:

[image]

The problem seems to disappear if I give a plain text to the `QLabel` in `ItemWidget`, such as `label = QLabel("text")`, why? What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting rich text content causes the mouse button release event to be always accepted (I suppose it's due to the fact that rich text can contain links).

The view must receive a mouse release event in order to call its `mouseReleaseEvent()` and eventually emit the `clicked` signal, but since the event was already accepted by the label, this won't happen.

If you don't need links in that text, just reset the text interaction flags:

```py
    label.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.NoTextInteraction)
```